# When To Run Virtual Environment in Tango With Django 1.7

Tags: django, python-2.7, virtualenv

I am following along with the [Tango With Django 1.7](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/index.html) tutorial and have a quick question about virtual environments.  I just finished Chapter 3 and have successfully set up a virtual environment, but in Chapter 4 when we actually create a Django project it doesn't say whether or not I should be doing it in my virtual environment. I don't know the first thing about virtual environments, so I don't know if creating the project in the virtual environment actually matters or not.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could explain why I should or should not create my project in the virtual environment, or if it even matters. Thank you!

Comment: This is actually covered in the section you've already read: *"What if you had another Python application that requires a different version to run? Or you wanted to switch to the new version of Django, but still wanted to maintain your Django 1.7 project?"* It is easier to do the rest of the tutorial in your `virtualenv`, then you don't have to worry about other packages or upgrades.

Comment: Okay, so using a virtual environment is mainly to avoid potential conflicts?

Comment: There is extensive material on the internet already about what `virtualenv` is for and why and when to use it; perhaps you could do some research and come back if there are still questions you can't answer?